# What is bi-direction protocol in TChannel?

Tags: protocols, frame

I have read about TChannel which is a networking framing protocol used for general RPC. 
https://github.com/uber/tchannel/blob/master/docs/protocol.md
But I misunderstand some concepts.
"Tchannel is a bi-directional request/response protocol. Each connection between peers is considered equivalent, regardless of which side initiated it. It's possible, perhaps even desirable, to have multiple connections between the same pair of peers. Message ids are scoped to a connection. It is not valid to send a request down one connection and a response down another."
What is bi-direction protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Start considering the "request/response" part in the statement. It means that for every successful request sent by the host A there will be always a response sent back by host B.

This does not necessarly implies a syncronous behaviour (e.g. A block waiting for B's reply). Indeed TChannel works with an async behavior. Many requests can be sent in sequence, and the requester expects an out of order responses. In this way, the slow requests do not block faster requests.
How this work? Very simple. A specifies a message id when sending a request.  When B responds, it uses the same message id for the response. In this way A can easily correlate a response with the corresponding request.

Now look at the "bi-directional" part in the statement. It means that if host B wants to send a request to host A, it can re-use the same channel that was created originally by A. Despite there is a request/response logic, A and B are considered peers, and each connection between peers is considered equivalent, regardless of which host initiated it.